# Use asyncpg python module in alpine docker image

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, asyncpg

I'm trying to build an image based on `python:3-8.alpine`, using the python module `asyncpg`.

Here is a part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add python3-dev

RUN pip3 install asyncpg
```

I added `gcc` and `python3-dev` because I think I need them to be able to build `asyncpg` according to the documentation : https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/installation.html (but i'm not sure of that, I think I should be able to install without building this module)

But I have the following error when building the image:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.o -O2 -fsigned-char -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion
In file included from asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c:29:
/usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:10: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    11 | #include <limits.h>
       |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I solve this error and install `asyncpg` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install build tools not just gcc. Also you can remove `RUN apk add python3-dev` step. Since you're using python as the base image.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base

RUN pip3 install asyncpg
```

Build stdout

```
Step 3/3 : RUN pip3 install asyncpg
 ---> Running in e109c84feec3
Collecting asyncpg
  Downloading asyncpg-0.20.1.tar.gz (734 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: asyncpg
  Building wheel for asyncpg (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for asyncpg (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for asyncpg: filename=asyncpg-0.20.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=1337371 sha256=5a0dcfc8c327eb4068814a9bf0a1d9beee1b9c440c1100efcede8ef63b1dac09
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/22/c9/61/991ebd5df043025e222695b7c4bc84e527bf3f0239073f0ea2
Successfully built asyncpg
Installing collected packages: asyncpg
Successfully installed asyncpg-0.20.1
Removing intermediate container e109c84feec3
 ---> 21dacd97e784
Successfully built 21dacd97e784
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I was lookinf for!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `musl-dev` library.
Here is working Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip3 install asyncpg
```