# async python error while running api in docker asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-asyncio, quart

I am making an api in  quart which is based on aiohttp in python and its an asynchronous library
and when i run the api locally everything runs fine but if i run it on docker it gives me **errors on endpoints**

```sh
api_1  |   File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 301, in query
api_1  |   File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 664, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
api_1  | asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

This is on an endpoint which works fine locally

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

# left to be done after project structure
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
CMD python launch.py initdb
CMD sh /app/runfile.sh
```

runfile.sh

```sh
hypercorn launch:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Dockerfile after applying change that was suggested

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# left to be done after project structure
WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN apk add gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
CMD python launch.py initdb
CMD sh /app/runfile.sh
```

Comment: Did you confirm whether code runs in host machine?

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI yes api runs, the endpoints work locally and on server as well without docker but  with docker the api starts without any problem but and only endpoints give error when a db operation has been made **in docker only**

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343455/use-asyncpg-python-module-in-alpine-docker-image) must help you.

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI https://imgur.com/jlUpZr6 same error :sad:

Answer (score 0):

I have found [a solution](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/258). The problem is lacking of connections in pool. so await connection with using `acquire()` like as mentioned above.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/258#issuecomment-650276156) says don't share connection pool in different worker. Why don't you try to run as single worker? Then, increase it.